# Disallow Caret inside HTML anchor tags

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have a `contenteditable` paragraph containing multiple anchor tags as shown below. Each anchor tag contains text with square brackets. Assume the Pipe is the caret:

```
<p contenteditable='true'>This is some <a>[text]|</a>. Here is some <a>[more]</a></p>
```

After a user has typed a key, How do I detect if the caret is between the closing square bracket on the left and the closing anchor tag on the right and if so, move it to the right of the closing anchor tag to prevent typing into the anchor tag.

I have been through about a half dozen posts including this one: [contenteditable put caret outside inserted span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574522/contenteditable-put-caret-outside-inserted-span)

However none of them address my specific need. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Set the anchors to not be contenteditable and the person will not be able to edit the text inside of it. (They can however delete it)

```html
<p contenteditable='true'>This is some <a contenteditable="false">[text]</a>. Here is some <a contenteditable="false">[more]</a></p>
```

and to allow them to edit just the text inside

```html
<p contenteditable='true'>This is some <a contenteditable="false">[<span contenteditable='true'>text</span>]</a>. Here is some <a contenteditable="false">[<span contenteditable='true'>more</span>]</a></p>
```

Comment: So you only want the text inside the `[]` to be editable? @TripleC

Comment: So than you need to nest them! Got to love all the extra html mark up. :)

Comment: The whole anchor tag and it's contents are editable. I just want to disallow the cursor being between the text "]" and the html `</a>.' What is happening is I am editing the paragraph and sometimes I am typing after the closing square bracket and getting a different style because the cursor is technically "inside" the anchor tag.

Comment: And that is what the code above in the second example does. You can change any of the text between the [ and ], but you can not enter text before [ and after ].

Comment: The brackets are also editable. As I said previously, "The whole anchor tag and it's contents need to be editable."

Comment: So than put them inside of the span... I am confused what your issue is, but from what I thought it was, those were my answers...